# C++ library that implements a file cache like a web browser

Tags: c++, caching, browser-cache

Is there a generic C++ library for implementing a file caching system? This is the closest that I've found fits my requirements: https://github.com/openwebos/filecache.  Here are my requirements:

1. cache data on the file system by a unique hash
2. occasionally cleans the cache to make sure it doesn't overflow
3. lock cache data so it doesn't get culled during a cache clean
4. store and allow querying of timestamp information

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it meets all of your needs, but check out this: [jupiterfilecache](http://code.google.com/p/jupiterfilecache/)